# (Discordia) How to make bot edit to its own specific message?

Tags: lua, discord

So i got my bot sending a message using a variable which is: `local text1 = message:reply("Text")`,
but cannot seem find some answers of how to edit the message variable. i even tried using `text1:edit("New Text")` and doesn't seem to work, Anyone with experience of Discordia mind help if you know how to make a bot edit it's own message? Here's my bot code:

```
local discordia = require('discordia')
local client = discordia.Client()
local token = "BOT TOKEN"

client:on('messageCreate', function(message)

    if message.content == "hello" then
        local text1 = message:reply("Text")
        text1:edit("This message has been editted!")
    end

client:run("Bot "..token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia/blob/7246e0d400b6788a41d10419290f22f19f95bf2f/libs/containers/Message.lua#L176)

```
text1:setContent("This message has been edited!")
```

or

```
text1:update{content = "This message has been edited!"}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki and the Discordia;
for updating the content of your message object 'text1' should be

```
text1:setContent("This is a new content")
```

To learn more about it, please check https://github.com/SinisterRectus/Discordia/wiki